# In which format Quartz.net stores the times

Tags: c#, datetime-format, quartz.net

Does anybody know in which format quartz.net stores the times in the QUARTZ_TRIGGERS table. For example I have seen  634019848980000000 in NEXT_FIRE_TIME column, but I am unable to get the exact date time.

It will be very helpful if I can get this. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

634019848980000000 == 2/17/2010 6:28:18 AM
it is tickcount.

```
    DateTime d = new DateTime(634019848980000000);
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
```